# Использование data()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один блок, закрывался другой(тот который был открыт ранее). А так же, чтобы блок закрывался и при нажатии на самого себя. Заранее спасибо. Есть код:

```
if (screen.width <= 991) {
    $(".reviews-tab-items-content").unbind(); 
    $(".reviews-tab-items-content").on('click',function(e){
        console.log('ttttttttttttttww');
        $(this).find(".hidden-text").slideToggle();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например вот так: В data-close вставляем селектор, который при клике на объект закроется

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){

  $(".item").on('click', function(){
    //Если блок по которому кликаем скрыт показываем его
    if($(this).find('.toggle-content').css('display') == 'none'){
      //Скрываем все toggle-content
      $(".toggle-content").hide();
      //Показываем текущий
      $(this).find(".toggle-content").show();
    }else{
      //Инчае скрываем все
      $(".toggle-content").hide();
    }
    
  });

});
```

```css
.item{
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-content{
display: none;
padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Первый блок, при клике закроет второй
  <div class="toggle-content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis nisi quis dolor ullamcorper dapibus. Praesent malesuada augue tincidunt erat congue rhoncus. 
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item">
2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Второй закроет третий
  <div class="toggle-content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis nisi quis dolor ullamcorper dapibus. Praesent malesuada augue tincidunt erat congue rhoncus. 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Третий закроет первый
  <div class="toggle-content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis nisi quis dolor ullamcorper dapibus. Praesent malesuada augue tincidunt erat congue rhoncus. 
  </div>
</div>
```

UPD для такого не нужны data атрибуты.
UPD 2 при клике на открытый блок, он закроется

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, этот вариант подойдет для вот такого?http://prntscr.com/jigthn То есть если блок открыт, и при нажатии на второй, тот который был открыт, закрывается?

Comment: @ВладиславМалышко те нужно что бы было 2 блока, при клике на который они бы разворачивались, но если уже есть развернутый, при клике на другой он бы сворачивался. Надеюсь вы меня поняли, если да, могу пока изменить

Comment: @ВладиславМалышко посмотрите ответ, изменил по новому условию. Для такой реализации не нужны дата атрибуты

Comment: @ВладиславМалышко поправил, там уже selector не нужен. Если ответ правильный, можете отметить его как верный

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста, правильно ли у меня записано? http://prntscr.com/jih1ro и еще один вопросик, как сделать чтобы не только если на другой блок нажать, будет закрываться предыдущий. Нужно чтобы и при  нажатии на этот же блок, он закрылся)

Comment: Подскажите как можно сделать?

Comment: @ВладиславМалышко сейчас сделаю, что бы закрывался)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ВладиславМалышко а зачем вы удалили вопрос? верните, тут так не принято =/

Comment: Думал что никто уже не ответит, вот и удалил( Уже восстановил)

Comment: @ВладиславМалышко обновил

Comment: Спасибо большое!